# if statement shell script error

Tags: bash, shell

Hello I don't know if this will be a duplicate , but I really don't see the error in this piece of code . It gives me an error at the then statement and I think there is no error . 
I have putted comments on the two lines where the code breaks .
Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter first value:"
read firstvar
echo -n "Enter second value:"
read secondvar
echo -n "Enter last value:"
read compvar
echo -n "Enter operation:"
read ops
counter=0
result=0
while [ $result -eq $compvar ]
do
if [ $ops -eq "+" ]
then result = $((firstvar+secondvar))
elif [ $ops -eq "-" ]
then result = $((firstvar-secondvar))
#elif[ $ops -eq "*" ]
#then result = $((firstvar\*secondvar))
#elif[ $ops -eq "/" ]
#then result = $((firstvar/secondvar))
else
echo "Input valid operation !!!"
fi
(($counter++))
done
```

Comment: Saying that "there is an error" without telling the exact error message and location of the error, is like going to the doctor and saying "it hurts somewhere" without saying where and how it hurts.

Comment: Use [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) before posting

Comment: Yes thanks , I found my error . Sorry for bothering .

Comment: `-eq` is to compare numbers, not strings.

Comment: Why is this a `elif` chain at all?  Use `case $ops in ....`

Answer (score 0):

Oh shoot , I m retarded . Missed the space between "elif" and the "[" .

Comment: You have more problems than that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn how to space and indent to have your code legible.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter first value:";  read firstvar
echo -n "Enter second value:"; read secondvar
echo -n "Enter last value:";   read compvar
echo -n "Enter operation:";    read ops

counter=0; result=0     #initialize variables
while [ $result -eq $compvar ]; do
   if [ $ops = "+" ]; then
      result = $((firstvar+secondvar))
   elif [ $ops = "-" ]; then
      result=$((firstvar-secondvar))       
   else
      echo "Input valid operation !!!"
   fi
   ((++counter))
done
```

Writing code is the same as writing literature.  There are forms to use to make it easy for the reader (even if it's just you 6 months later) to follow.  Your code above is confusing, and will bite you on the butt later.  Add comments to.

The while loop is gratuitous and will do nothing-- the -eq should at least be -ne.  The counter could be initialized as an integer to avoid problems that could arise, but it's also never used.